# Insert/update trigger updating column value of all rows

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, triggers

I am running into a logical problem.My Trigger is:

```
 create trigger Points1
 on Posts
 after insert, update
 As
 declare @value int
 declare @postedby int
 select @value= Count(Message) from Posts
 select @postedby = PostedBy from Posts

update AspNetUsers set User_points = @value * 3
where ( AspNetUsers.Id = @postedby)
```

I dont know whether i am doing it right or not.

Two tables: AspNetUsers table with User_points column and Id Column as primary key

Posts table with PostId as primary key and PostedBy as foreign key referencing the AspNetUsers table.

Now, i want to compare PostedBy with Id column and if they both are same then update the User_Points column with +3 on every single message he posted.

Now, problem is:
1> It is inserting same number of points in every Row.It should check only currently inserted row and the PostedBy column of that row and then compare with Id column of other table and should Update user's Point of only that Id.

But same result nothing happens
Please tell me how to do it. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

change

```
select @postedby = PostedBy from Posts
```

to

```
select @postedby = PostedBy from INSERTED
```

'INSERTED' is a magic table that keep insert/updated data in this scope. 
Same as this 'DELETED' table keep previous data in update a row

Comment: still same results updating multiple rows column @Musthaan

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if the `INSERT` statement affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @postedBy = PostedBy FROM Inserted` - it's non-deterministic - you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you'll **ignore all others**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: thanks for ur reply sir, i am struggling at last line in where condition. i have used same parameters and tried to insert values in a new table to see what @postedBy contains. insert into Employee_Demo(PostedBy, TotalCount)
values (@postedby,@value );        but there it is inserting correct value but fails in update condition